# Cropping in pillow. (discord.py)

Tags: discord.py, python-imaging-library

i need a help. How to make pillow clipping my progress bar against current exp. Because currently I have using resize but unfortunately when someone has little exp it does not look good, so I would like to make the bot trim my progress bar from right relative to missing exp
This is my actually code:

```py
    rectangle = Image.open("progress-bar.png")
    rectangle = rectangle.resize((round(rectangle.size[0] * exp / lev), rectangle.size[1]))

    levelcard.paste(rectangle, (440, 376))


    levelcard.save("profile2.png")

    await ctx.reply(file=discord.File("profile2.png"))
```

(and rectangle.crop don't work)
(I want it to sort of crop the middle of my progress bar (I can show you a picture) so that the beginning of the bar and the end of the bar are rounded, because when I use resize it just makes my bar square on both sides)

Comment: Please try to improve your question. What is an `exp`? What does the thing you are trying to trim look like? How should it look when it's been trimmed?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: Please give more information and a more In-Depth explanation of your problem, the example picture you mentioned would be of great use to understand what you need.

Secondly: Are you sure you want to resize the progressbar to the exp divided by the level? That doesn't seem like it would work.

If the levels don't exponentially increase, and the exp goes to 0 every level up, then you might wanna just do the exp multiplied by this magical number `x_pixel_size_of_progressbar / max_xp_to_level_up`. IE: if the x size of the progressbar is 200, and the max xp is 100, the magic number is 2 (200 / 100 = 2), so if you had full xp, the xp bar would be full (100 * 2 = 200), so instead of `rectangle = rectangle.resize((round(rectangle.size[0] * exp / lev), rectangle.size[1]))`, you would do `rectangle = rectangle.resize((round(exp * (rectangle.size[0] / maxexp)), rectangle.size[1]))`

And if the exp doesn't go to 0 at levelup kind of like a "global" xp system, then you can do something like `this_levels_xp = exp - (levup_xp * lev)` and then apply the stuff mentioned before.